# how to use mythlink.pl

Tags: mythtv

I have been trying to understand how to use mythlink.pl.  I would like the mythtv recordings to have a readable title.  I have read several articles and posts on different forums, but I still do not understand how to execute the script.  is there any dependencies that I need to install?  It is very unclear to me.  Any assistance will be appreciated.  sister5091

Answer (score 0):

`mythlink.pl` is typically located at `/usr/share/doc/mythtv-backend/contrib/user_jobs/mythlink.pl`.

you can run it from a terminal, as a chron, or as a User Job (in mythtv).